# Lumen freshly installed give 500 error ( view() and other things do not work )

Tags: php, lumen

For the first time in my life I had to install PHP, Apache and MySQL myself before using the server. So I may have made a mistake somewhere.

Here is my problem :
I installed Lumen (8.2.4) with Composer and, at first glance, it worked.
My website root show :

```
Lumen (8.2.4) (Laravel Components ^8.0)
```

But when I change the routes/web.php code for this :

```php
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return view('test');
});
```

-> it doesn't work anymore. The server return a **500 error** and my browser show an empty blank page.

I've got the **same issue** if I try to run a **database query**. -> 500 internal server error

**If someone have an idea of what could be the cause of this problem, please tell me.**

I check the requirements for Lumen and, as far as I understand those things, it seems that I meet all of them.

Lumen requirements : [Lumen installation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation)

- PHP >= 7.3
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension

My PHP version : **7.3.31**

Here are some extracts of phpinfo() :
[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT : More informations :**

I already uncommented $app->withFacades() like described in the documentation.

If I try to return a plain string without using view(), it works. If I try a single string inside a test.blade.php file, it doesn't work.

Apache error log is empty, Lumen logs are non-existant.

Comment: Few questions: Did you uncommented $app->withFacades() like described here https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/views? Do you get same error when returning plain string instead of view? Can you access Apache error log?

Comment: @jakob I edit my post (at the bottom) to answer your questions. (Thanks for your interest.)